# sublime regular expression to add isset for all variables

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I have code like below

```
$list['name'] =  $obj->name;
$list['desc'] = $obj->desc;
```

and so on (I have more than 1000 lines like this in various functions).

I want to add isset for all the variables before assigning

```
$list['name'] = isset($obj->name)?$obj->name:'';
$list['desc'] = isset($obj->desc)?$obj->desc:'';
```

Is this possible to do using regular expression search and replace in sublime? 
Or is there any other best way to do it fast than do it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something such as this might work:

Find Pattern:

```
^(.*\] = {1,2})(\$obj->\w+[^;]);
```

Replace Pattern:

```
\1isset(\2)?\2:'';
```

**Example**:

https://regex101.com/r/ZQbAp0/1

```
^ asserts position at start of a line

1st Capturing Group (.*\] = {1,2})
.* matches any character (except for line terminators)
\] matches the character ] literally (case sensitive)
 = matches the characters  = literally (case sensitive)
 {1,2} Quantifier — Matches between 1 and 2 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

2nd Capturing Group (\$obj->\w+[^;])
\$ matches the character $ literally (case sensitive)
obj-> matches the characters obj-> literally (case sensitive)
\w+ matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
Match a single character not present in the list below [^;]
; matches the character ; literally (case sensitive)
```

Comment: Awesome. It is exactly working as like i wanted. But can you do me one more favor? I want to search `$array_name['array_key'];` and replace that with `isset($array_name['array_key'])?$array_name['array_key']:'';` I tried modifying the regular expression to achieve that and still trying. But if you have an answer, that will save lots of my time. Thanks again :)

Comment: That one should be fairly easy, although is `$array_name` always the same prefix as with `array_key`? so `array` would match in both places. Basically that would be find pattern `\$(.+)(_name\[')(\1)(_key'\];) ` and replace `isset(\1)?\1:'';`...

Comment: I really agree your answer. But my array key is dynamic and it is big. This is parsing xml elements to array. So my array element looks like  `$tag_detail['/product-biitem/association-ends[1]/association-end[1]/target[1]/reference-to-product-contract[1]/product-contract-key[1]/key-type-for-cbe-standard[1]/object-id[1]']` .I need to add isset for this kind of array element. Thanks for your answer. that helped me in some other cases. If this is some easy stuff, then that would help me a lot. ;) :)

Comment: Well that makes it more difficult, in the sense that you have less to work with. Basically you want to have something specific in your pattern so that it doesn't go replacing anything it's not supposed to. So really what you want is to find something unique about your array to avoid this. If you are daring though try doing `^\$(.+)(\['.+'\])`, `isset(\1\2)?\$\1\2:'';`... the replace ends up being a monster!

Answer (score 1):

I had a non-programing approach to do this, without regex:

Sublime Text 3 has [Multiple Selections](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/selection) to let you edit multiple lines at same the time. To use it, simply select lines you want to edit and click `Ctrl + Shift + L`.

Let's do the trick:

1. Select 1000 lines you like to edit. Click `Ctrl + Shift + L` to enter multiple selection. It looks like:

   [image]
2. Click `End` to go to the end of selected lines.
3. Use `Ctrl + Arrows` and `Ctrl + Shift` to select `$obj->name`. Remember to use `Ctrl + Arrows` so you can select correct `$obj->xxxxx` regardless of the word length.
4. Click `Ctrl + c` to copy them.
5. Go to left side of `$obj->name` and type `isset(`. Go to right side and type `)?`.
6. `Ctrl + v` to paste all the copies to corresponding lines.
7. Click `End` and type `:'';` to the end.

And we're done! Here's the result:
[image]